# Error message: can not resolve method Create(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener,int)

Tags: android-studio

I wish to play a specific music file from raw folder in Android Studio, on click of a specific button. However I get the following response:

> Error message -can not resolve method ' Create(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener,int)

My code is as below:

```java
Button t1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose_Tamil1);
t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mediaPlayer =MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.melam);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Button t1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose_Tamil1);
t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View view) { 
        mediaPlayer =MediaPlayer.create(CLASSNAME.this,R.raw.melam); 
    } 
});
```

And replace **CLASSNAME** with the name of the current class in which you are working in.

The error was because `this` keyword was referring to the `OnClickListener` class in general, but it should have referred to the custom `OnClickListener` class you wrote within your current class.

Hence the change.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

mediaPlayer =MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.melam);